# are there errors in my code?

Tags: jquery

Not a clue what to call this question as it is an odd one.

Basically I have this code that moves an image slider along based on interactions with the left and right arrows. It worked fine yesterday and today after changing absolutely nothing it stopped working.

I'm assuming I've missed out a ; or a } or even a ) because this always seems to be the case with these stupid errors. I'm gunna run through and strip everything out to see where the problem is but in the mean time could someone look over this and just double check everything is written as it should be?

```
$(function(){   
    $("#rightArrow").hover(function() {
        $('.projectImages').animate({left: '-270px'}, 3000);
    });

    $("#leftArrow").hover(function() {
        $('.projectImages').animate({left: '0px'}, 3000);
    });

    $("#rightArrow").click(function() {
        $('.projectImages').css('left', '-270px');
        $('.projectImages').stop();
    });

    $("#leftArrow").click(function() {
        $('.projectImages').css('left', '0px');
        $('.projectImages').stop();
    });

    $(".arrow").mouseout(function() {
        $('.projectImages').stop();
    });
});
```

Cheers,
Sam

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RnQj7/ and click on jsLint and you will see whether your code is correct or not.

Comment: I should have mentioned. Instead of moving when the arrows are hovered over and stopping afterwards, once you hover over any of the buttons it begins a loop that appears to be.

$(".projectImages').animate({left:'-270px'}).delay(25000).animate({left:'0'}).delay(25000);

Comment: Sorry I completely do not understand - can you provide your CSS and Markup please

Comment: Never mind it's sorted, still no idea what it was doing though.

Comment: it does not work in no way? or it does not work as expected?
also missing the CSS file.
Has the container of class "projectImages" the css property  position: relative ?
It works for me with proper CSS.

Comment: The question has already been answered. It was because the .hover event was being called on mouseover and on mouseout causing some weird animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should try this way:

```
$("#rightArrow").hover(function() {
    $('.projectImages').animate({left: '-270px'}, 3000);
},function() {
    $('.projectImages').stop();
});

$("#leftArrow").hover(function() {
    $('.projectImages').animate({left: '0px'}, 3000);
},function() {
    $('.projectImages').stop();
});
```

`$.hover(infunc,outfunc)` is a two parameter function, short version of for this: `$.mouseenter(infunc).mouseleave(outfunc)`

**EDIT:** using `mouseover` and `mouseout` like Felix said is the best way imho.

Comment: This works as well. I think I'll use this with it being slightly less code. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by *stopped working*? What is it doing?

Try to bind to `mouseover` (or `mouseenter`) instead of `hover`:

```
$("#rightArrow").mouseover(function() {
    $('.projectImages').animate({left: '-270px'}, 3000);
});

$("#leftArrow").mouseover(function() {
    $('.projectImages').animate({left: '0px'}, 3000);
});
```

If you only pass one function to `hover`, this function will be called on `mouseenter` **and** `mouseleave`.

Comment: Spot on that mate, ta.

Weird how .hover worked fine yesterday though